# how can I use internal resource (e.g. R.id.myImage01) as an email attachment?

Tags: android

how can I use internal resource (e.g. R.drawable.myImage01) as an email attachment?
I tried the following code. It shows the file is attach but actually the email gets send without any attachment.

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();   
String imagePath = context.getFilesDir() + "/" + "myImage01.png";
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(imagePath));
```

Thanks
Azam

Answer (score 1):

As it's an internal resource, the email client won't be able to access to that file. Thus, you have to copy the image to the SDCard, and then attach that file.

Answer (score 1):

The other option would be a content provider. Use a URL like

```
"content://com.example.myapp/images/" + R.drawable.myImage01
```

and then use the provided ID to stream the content to the client.

(That is, I assume that this will work.)

Comment: Yes, this works, but it means going through the effort of writing a content provider and overriding ContentProvider.openFile.